# Multiple alignments from top of page on a single page

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment

I am trying to specify the location of text from the top of a page.  I know how to set the margins for the main text and can set the top, bottom, left, and right margins for certain pages using the `\newgeometry` command, but I need to positing the title 2.5 inches from the top of the page and a horizontal line 4.5 inches from the top of the page.  I use the `\vspace*{\fill}` command to position the copyright at the bottom of the page.

My question is how do I position text in the middle of a page a specified distance from the top of a page without using `\vspace`. Here are the [actual distances from the top of the page](http://www.research.uky.edu/gs/CurrentStudents/Documents/DissertationExample09-11.pdf) I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`textpos` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) for such placement.  Here is a simple example placing some text centered and 2.5in from the top of the page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(0in,2.5in)
  \centering
  Sample Text
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]